# Checking whether a file is an audio file using Python and the sndhdr module

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio

I'm creating a small python program that iterates through a folder structure and performs a task on every audio file that it finds.

I need to identify which files are audio and which are 'other' (e.g. jpegs of the album cover) that I want the process to ignore and just move onto the next file.

From searching on StackOverflow/Google/etc the sndhdr module appears at the top of most lists - I can't seem to get the sndhdr.what() method to return anything but 'None' though, no matter how many *.mp3 files I throw at it. My outline implementation is below, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
def import_folder(folder_path):
''' Imports all audio files found in a folder structure

:param folder_path: The absolute path of the folder
:return: True/False depending on whether the process was successful
'''

# Remove any spaces to ensure the folder is located correctly
folder_path = folder_path.strip()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for file in files:
        audio_file = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        print sndhdr.what(audio_file)
        # The 'real' method will perform the task here
```

For example:

```
rootdir = '/home/user/FolderFullOfmp3Files'
import_folder(rootdir)
>>> None
>>> None
>>> None
...etc
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question... but I'm curious as to why use `sndhr.what` over file.endswith(".mp3") to check for mp3 files?

Comment: Try calling `sndhdr.what('/a/literal/string/of/the/actual/path.mp3')`.

Comment: @Slayer: The file could be a *.wav file or have no file extension in the filename

Comment: @Cyphase: sndhdr.what('/home/adam/Music/blackdog.mp3' ) returned 'None' as well (unless I've misunderstood what you meant by 'literal string'?)

Comment: @AdamDynamic, you didn't misunderstand :). And you're _sure_ that file exists and is an MP3?

Comment: 100% sure the file is an audio file (just listened to the first few seconds to check :)

Answer (score 0):

It very much looks like the [sndhdr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sndhdr.html) module of the standard library recognizes only file types that the standard library is also able to actually open ('aifc', 'aiff', 'au', 'hcom', 'sndr', 'sndt', 'voc', 'wav', '8svx', 'sb', 'ub', or 'ul').
MP3 is not supported natively (nor OGG, FLAC, ...).

You can try [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) for detecting all kinds of file types (not only audio files).

Depending on your OS, you can also call the operating-system command `file` on your files and parse the result with Python.

You can also just perform whatever task you want to do on the files and just use `try`/`except` to check if an exception occured.

Comment: `python-magic` did not detect an MP3 file for me. It just says it's `'data'`

Answer (score 0):

**Using moviepy.editor to detect an audio file:**

```
pip install moviepy
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip as a_clip
is_audio_file = False
try:
    audio = a_clip('audio-file-path.mp3')
    is_audio_file = True
except Exception:
    print("An exception occurred here")
    pass

print(f"It's {'' if is_audio_file else 'NOT'} an audio file")
```

You should beware of execution time.